# rename excel workbook in c#

Tags: c#, excel

I would like to know how to rename an excel workbook using Microsoft.Office.Interop dll?
I use an xlsx file to create my new workbook. I know that the Name attribute of Workbook class is just reading.

```
Excel.Workbook classeur = xlsApp.Workbooks.Add(path + "\\Template.xlsx");
```

anybody know?
Thank you

Comment: I've got the same problem as @CERVERA -- How do you change the open spreadsheet's name using the Excel Interop? Or, how do you open a Excel file you just created with a specific filename from the temp folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to rename a file in C#, you can use this method :

```
System.IO.File.Move(oldFileName, NewFileName);
```

If you really want to use Office methods, the [SaveAs method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.saveas%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) can be useful, then you delete the old file.